# Will identifierForVendor change if I restore from a backup on same device?

Tags: ios, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I can't find precise information on that in the API doc. Are there any experiences if the `identifierForVendor` changes if the app was restored on same device via cloud backup / local backup?

At the moment I am creating that identifier and store it in the keychain. But I am interested if I can additionally check if the identifier is the same after a cloud restore for example.